# SceneKit crashes when I use constraint and minimize App

Tags: swift, scenekit, exc-bad-access, arkit

I have very strange behavior in my app, that I can't explain. I have a `SceneKit` session running, and some `nodes` have `constraints` assigned (no matter what kind). When app goes to background I'm removing all `nodes` from the `scene`, and when it appears again I'm adding them again (This is needed for reasons not needed here). When I have this `constraints` assigned and resume app - it crashes. Not always, but very often. I have no idea what to do to fix this. I tried removing `constraints` when removing `nodes`, but this did not help. The error I get is in a screenshot. Can someone help me find a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't show the code that you are referencing, but I can tell you that an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error typically means you are trying to access an object that has been released from memory.

Without going in depth about [strong vs. weak](https://krakendev.io/blog/weak-and-unowned-references-in-swift) variables, you likely have a `weak` or `unowned` variable (to that constraint) that is becoming `nil` and that you are trying to access (by force-unwrapping).

When you are removing these nodes, or when the view disappears, the constraint is released from memory. So the fix here is to either make the reference to this constraint `strong` or to make a new constraint, keep a strong reference to that in the class, and assign that constraint to the object.

Assuming your reference is to a storyboard, replace:

`@IBOutlet weak var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`

With:

`@IBOutlet var constraint: NSLayoutConstraint!`

Also note that the variable is probable force-unwrapped (`NSLayoutConstraint!`), which is likely why you are running into the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Set your constraint to be a strong variable instead of weak, or better yet, avoid force-unwrapping optionals if possible!

*Note: If this doesn't solve your problem, leave a comment after adding more details to your question.*

Comment: Actually I meant `SCNConstraint`, and not `NSLayoutConstraint` - sory, I should be more specific. Anyway here is not the manner of weak/unowned property, as this constraint is only assigned straight to `SCNNode.constraints`.

Comment: Okay! I won't change my answer, though. An EXC_BAD_ACCESS error means that you're force-unwrapping a variable that is `nil` or essentially accessing something that no longer exists. Hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible that this is an error in SDK? If it was in my code, should I see some functions written by me in thread stack?

Comment: Is it possible that the SDK isn't perfect, yes! But in this case I'd say it's very unlikely. Try to use the debugger to find the exact point in your code that the app crashes and determine if that variable is an Optionally unwrapped type. For example, `SCNConstraint!` or `SCNConstraint?`